# Azure ARM REST API for manipulating Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I believe Azure ARM does support Azure Functions because obviously this GitHub project https://github.com/sedouard/azure-functions-node is calling ARM to create/get/list/delete Azure Functions. But I couldn't find anything about Azure Functions on Azure REST API Reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/).

Is it an officially supported feature in ARM to manipulate Azure Functions?
Where can I find the complete (and up-to-date) documentation of Azure ARM REST API for Azure Functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Functions is built on top of App Service, and ARM is indeed supported.

You can find links to the REST API and template format for Function Apps under the [Web & Mobile section here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services#web--mobile)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I indeed found a link of "Function App REST" under the section you mentioned. However the link brought me to a web page where I still could not find anything directly related to "functions". Based on my reading of the code in the GitHub project I mentioned in my original post, there seems to be some APIs like `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{functionAppName}/functions/...`. But I didn't see anything like that in the documentation.

Comment: Functions shares the Web App APIs. There are no functions specific ARM APIs, but some function specific properties and settings, and provisioning/management is identical to web. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: For example, I want to (through code) 1) list all the function apps I have; 2) list all the functions under a function app; 3) get information (language, trigger type, definition) of a particular function; 4) create/delete function apps; 5) create/delete functions; 6) update function code. etc.

Comment: 1 and 4 are available (your Function App is an ARM resource). 2, 3, 5 and 6 are not, and you'd need to use something like source control, Functions Core Tools (CLI), or Kudu VFS APIs

Comment: Thanks! I think I agree with you about 1, 4, and 6. But regarding 2, 3, and 5, I'm still not very sure... Looking at this GitHub project [https://github.com/sedouard/azure-functions-node/blob/master/modules/azure-functions.js](https://github.com/sedouard/azure-functions-node/blob/master/modules/azure-functions.js), it is indeed calling ARM to list/get/create(deploy)/delete functions. Could it be the Azure REST API documentation not up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, while those technically do exist, they're pass-through APIs going into *very limited* Kudu APIs that expose basic function management. Those support a very narrow set of scenarios, and are primarily in place to support some internal functionality. If they meet your requirements, you can use them, they'll fall short once you need to deal with larger payload sizes, binaries, etc.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks Fabio!